# append div tag Into anchor tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Greeting..

In Browser Html is

```
<div tabIndex="0" title="People Picker" class="ms-inputuserfield">Administrator</div>
```

i want to replacewith look like

```
<a href='#'> <div tabIndex="0" title="People Picker" class="ms-inputuserfield">Administrator</div></a>
```

i tried to so much for make this. not succeed yet.
plz Help me.

i try by this code :

```
 var list = $("<a href='#' />");
 $(list).wrapInner($('#maindiv').html())
 $('div.ms-inputuserfield').replaceWith(list);
```

i knew that i am going wrong way.its replace by anchor.

Comment: Ok might want to post some code, explain more what you are trying to do.

Comment: In any case this is invalid HTML. The anchor element may only contain other inline elements.

Comment: @Dejan i did edit my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could do

```
$('div.ms-inputuserfield').wrap('<a href="#"/>');
```

EDIT - fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/QUcux/

If it's not working, remeber that you must put it in document.ready()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.ms-inputuserfield').wrap('<a href="#"/>');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the jQuery wrap method.

```
$('div.ms-inputuserfield').wrap('<a href="#" />');
```

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Thanks